# Airflow: retry task with different parameter or settings

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm executing a query that sometimes will fail because of the setting of one parameter.
To set it on the 'safe' side is not desired, as this greatly affects performance in a negative way.
So I'd love to retry the same task on failure, but with a changed value for this parameter.

Is there a 'native' way of doing this in Airflow?
Or should I use the 'try: except:' way and work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Having example code would help answer the question. But here's a generic example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


@dag(schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1))
def so_75553740():
    @task(retries=5, retry_delay=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0))
    def example(task_instance: TaskInstance = None):
        print(f"This is attempt #{task_instance.try_number}")
        if task_instance.try_number < 3:
            raise Exception("let's retry!")

    example()

    BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_example",
        retries=5,
        retry_delay=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0),
        bash_command="echo 'This is attempt #{{ task_instance.try_number }}' && exit {{ 1 if task_instance.try_number < 3 else 0 }}",
    )


so_75553740()
```

Using [templated variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) and [Jinja templating](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/operators.html#jinja-templating), you can modify the behavior depending on the `try_number`. `try_number` is an attribute on `task_instance`, which is a variable available at runtime. See the full list of variables available at runtime [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

If running a `PythonOperator` or `@task` decorator, you can fetch `task_instance.try_number` as a Python object and use that in your Python code.

However, if using an operator where you cannot supply arbitrary Python code, you can apply Jinja templating to modify behavior at runtime. Here, I used `{{ 1 if task_instance.try_number < 3 else 0 }}` to define the exit code based on the try number, but you can make this more complex (i.e. change a query) based on your needs.

Comment: thanks, apparently it's quite easy since there is an 'on_failure_callback' parameter on the operator that I can set to a function that changes the parameter, push it to xcom and pull it in the params setting in the operator